# How to update slider values?

Tags: dojo

I'd like to update valuemax value on a slider that people can only choose a value from 1 to 3, not to 5 like it is now. I have 'inspect the element' on the page, and got something like this:

> `<div dojoattachpoint="sliderHandle,focusNode" class="dijitSliderImageHandle dijitSliderImageHandleH" dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onHandleClick" wairole="slider" valuemin="1" valuemax="5" role="slider" aria-valuenow="3" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="years_label" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="5" style="position: absolute;"></div>`

I'm trying to find file/place on where that value can be updated in the code, however I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: You will need to change the source, the html on the webserver. Find it and change valuemax="5" to valuemax="3".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the source code for this application, change the javascript code that creates this slider widget.

You're looking at the DOM for the page in your example. You can use the `minimum` and `maximum` properties, which translates to some of the values you see in the DOM.  See the [Dojo dijit/form/Slider documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/form/Slider.html#dijit-form-slider) (takes you to 1.6 since it looks like you're using an older version of dojo because of the use of `dojoattachpoint`, those names changed in later versions of Dojo).

If you're not sure what class or widget this is in the source, look for the `id` element further up in the dom. Often that will have the package and class name as part of the id. Looking at the developer tools to see what files were loaded on the networking tab might give you a clue, if the application hasn't gone through any customer build or packaging to optimize it.